# How to retrieve values from php printed text fields and store them in a database?

Tags: php

Here is a piece of code

```
echo "<table>";
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sid'] ."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['qno'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ans'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='marks' value=''>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['d'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

With the values obtained from database, I also want to print textfields to enter marks into it..and then store those values in the respective rows of a table in database.
Please help. Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, sorry. What do you mean by "textfields" and "marks"? Ist this a cli or a web application? If storing is the only issue, then what is the problem? Use a database class and make an INSERT or UPDATE statement.

Comment: Make input fields with the value set to the value from the db? Then add a button that queries the database with the changes using an update query.

Comment: Just proceed as normal php form submission, it will work

Comment: Am developing an application in which one of the module requires the faculty to enter the marks for the student. For the same , am displaying the student roll (sid), question num (qno) and the answer he submitted (ans) and date on which he submitted (d) in the table format. And one more column should contain a text field for each row where the faculty will enter the marks after seeing his answer. Once the marks are entered, they have to be stored in the table 'marks' which already contain the sid , subject and assignment number.

Comment: Formatting your code nicely makes it easier for people to read and makes it more likely that they'll help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..

```
echo "<td><input type='text' class='marks' style='width:100%;' value='".$row['marks']."' name='marks[]'/></td>";
```

Access marks on forms submission as a regular php.

Comment: But marks is the name of the text field..it isn't the result of any query execution. How will it work in dat case?

Comment: The faculty should enter the marks and the entered values should be stored in database. It's not the other way round of retrieving the marks from database and displaying it in the text box.

Comment: ok. Then how to get the value from each text box and store it either in a table or pass it on to the next page?

Comment: Please read my last comment to the original post. It clearly specifies the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: You have to access marks field as an array and insert into database using loop. Please delete your comments.